# Which Azure AD Tenant will be chosen in the "common" endpoint when user has access to more than 1 tenant? Can the user control it?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

Assuming a Microsoft account that is a guest in several AAD tenants tries to authenticate to an AAD app that uses the "common" login endpoint with no way to select the required tenant.

1. Which AAD tenant will be chosen by AAD?
2. Is there a way to change AAD behavior to route the user into its non-default tenant?

Comment: You will be login to the directory which you had been  last time. E.g. You login into  A tenant with your guest account , then you change the directory to B.  Next time, when you try to login use that account, you will login to the B Tenant. Also, if you want to specify one tenant , you can change the `common` to be the domain of that tenant.

Comment: For 2., you can replace "common" with the tenant id you want them to log in.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!
In fact, the AAD app is one that I don't have access to and has the "common" endpoint hardcoded.

Comment: @juunas .  You're right, to specify one tenant, we should replace  `common`by `tenantId`. Thanks for your reminder.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Which AAD tenant will be chosen by AAD?

Currently, you will sign in to your last visited Directory.

> 2. Is there a way to change AAD behavior to route the user into its non-default tenant?

Currently, you can replace the `common` to be the `tenantId` of that tenant to specify one tenant.

## NOTE:

For this case, Azure Team has already started working on this. There will be a button called **Directory + subscription filter**  in Azure portal. This feature can let user to set his default directory with 2 options :

1. Sign in to your last visited Directory (This is the default option we are using currently).
2. Choose one directory from All directories as you want.

[image]

I believe that it won't take a long time to meet with us .

Hope this helps!

---

## UPDATE

This feature has been available now!

Comment: Hi, @Ido . Is this answer helpful ?

Comment: where is this option available (to choose from multiple available ads)? both adal.net and msal.net? how is it achieved? any documentation?